# Adding constraints programmatically disabled the touch up inside

Tags: ios, objective-c, menu, constraints

I have a side menu in my application and in its viewController I have: the rootView > view > and a scroll view containing a menuView. For some raisons I was forced to make the constraints programmatically for the menuView. The elements of the menuView are displayed correctly but the touch of every button of the menu element is not working anymore. The IBActions are set properly and every button is connected to its IBAction.

This is a part of my code:

```
[self.menuScrollView addSubview:self.menuView];

self.menuView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

NSLayoutConstraint *leading = [NSLayoutConstraint
                               constraintWithItem:self.menuView
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                               toItem:self.menuScrollView
                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                               multiplier:1.0f
                               constant:0.f];
```

I did the same think as the leading for the trailing and the top. After that I added every constraints in the menuScroll view. For example:

```
[self.menuScrollView addConstraint:leading];
```

Can anyone help me please?

**Edit:**

When I set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `YES`, the buttons are clicked but the scroll doesn't work.

Comment: Check in debug view heirarchy if there is a view getting created on top of your buttons. How are the views being layout?

Comment: I checked and there is no view in front of the menuView. Can it have a relation with the scrollView? In other words, can the scrollView detect the touchUpInside instead of my viewController?

Comment: If your button is a `subView` and you have made the `IBAction`(Basically as long as you can see the button and no view on top of it and outlets are set), there is no reason why the button action isn't getting performed. Are the the 'IBAction' set to 'touchUpInside' or something along that action? Umm just make sure that `userIntercation` is enabled for the button? Sometimes silly things get left.

Comment: All the userIntercation are enabled. Please see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

check for userinterationenable for all the super views. Constraints will not effect the user interactions.

check for scroll view content size also if its less than the width of the menu view then also user interaction will not work

Comment: I checked all the thinks you mentioned and I still having the same problem

Comment: there is a option in xcode to see the user interface inspector once check the  view hierarchy in that

Comment: mine worked with setting `superviews.isUserInteractionEnabled = true`